# Как создать триггер для считывания суммы?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Допустим, есть две таблицы Таблица1 и Таблица2. Поле1 Таблицы1 и Поле2 Таблицы2. Необходимо создать триггер, чтобы в Поле2 считывалась сумма всех значений Поля1.

Comment: Для того чтобы получить качественный ответ нужно задать качественный вопрос. Это третий вопрос по триггерам, который Вы задаете, и ни в одном нет ни слова о СУБД. Это принципиально, потому что в разных СУБД триггеры реализованы по разному, а телепатов здесь нет! В конце концов, есть метка "mssql".

Comment: SQL разве не метка. среда моя SQL Server

Comment: Есть MySQL, PostgresSQL, SQL Server, Oracle, FireBird и т.д. Везде есть SQL, и везде есть триггеры, но, повторюсь, в разных СУБД триггеры реализованы по разному.

Answer (score 1):

Кто придумывает вам такие задания?
Похоже, что сами. :-)
Нарисуйте пару таблиц с образцами данных.
Триггер - это правило типа "событие-условие-действие".

```
 1. Какое событие должно вызвать срабатывание триггера?
 2. Какое условие должно выполниться, чтобы выполнилось действие триггера?
 3. Какое действие должен выполнить триггер?
```

Вот на этих табличках и покажите.

Comment: Допустим, поступает несколько товаров в отдел(1товар по X цене, 2 товар по Y цене и т.д.,) по одной накладной. вот как просчитать итог по этой накладной. Сумму. Что нужно использовать Триггер, функцию или процедуру?!

Comment: 1. Вряд ли вы несколько товаров добавляете одним запросом. Значит триггер будет срабатывать на каждую вставку, считая промежуточные суммы.
2. Судя по всему, во второй таблице должен быть столбец с номером накладной. Есть там уже строка с этим номером, когда вы вставляете строки в первую таблицу?
3. Вы просите написать вам триггер, но не даете даже структуры таблиц.
Советую вам просто подсчитывать сумму в запросе, который будет формировать накладную.

Answer (score 1):

Как бы не на тему.

Как бы не писался Ваш триггер, но, помещая сумму стоимостей товара в таблицу, Вы нарушаете НФ Вашей схемы. Делать подобные вычисления надо с помощью представлений (запросов), а не помещать в таблицы суммы, разности и прочие интегралы ;-)). А если пользователю приспичит среднюю стоимость узнать, Вы еще одно поле будете создавать в таблице?

Comment: Тут Вы не совсем правы. Иногда частичная денормализация необходима для обеспечения требуемой производительности.

Comment: Думаю, что проблемы производительности тут не стоят. :-) Скорее всего это учебное задание типа "придумайте триггер, UDF и хп для какой-нибудь структуры".

Comment: @Modus. Рассуждения о д. мне вполне знакомы. Как правило, д. происходит 1)спонтанно из-за необходимиости изменений в схеме, связанных с коррекцией бизнес-правил; и 2) из-за неумения разработчика довести схему до 3 НФ или до Б.-К.  За денормализацию придется платить увеличением времени вставки и целостностью данных. 
Сначала надо бы научиться нормализовать. "Ты плохо-то не делай, ты хорошо делай. Плохо-то само получится."